# Log selection variable with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-analytics

I have a HTML form which involves the user making a selection from a series of images, each image has an onclick function which essentially turns them into checkboxes.  The selected image is then passed as a numerical value and matched with an array.

I need to somewhere keep a record of what was selected.  The important information is recording how many people chose image 1, how many chose image 2, etc..  Can I pass the selection variable to / and leverage Google Analytics to record that data?  I don't have a live Google Analytics account setup so I can't verify for myself at the moment.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', campId, 'selection', customerId, selectionID]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that'll work. I have Google Analytics set to track all outbound link clicks from my site, e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.heraldscotland.com/"
  onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article',
             'http://www.heraldscotland.com']);" 
  target="_blank">HeraldScotland</a>
```

And that data shows up within Behavior > Events > Top Events > Event Category > Event Action within Analytics looking something like this...

```
Event Action                Total Events    Unique Events   Event Value     Avg. Value
http://www.b2cqshop.com              30               29             0           0.00
http://stackoverflow.com              6                5             0           0.00
http://www.ikeahackers.net            3                3             0           0.00
http://www.adafruit.com               2                2             0           0.00
```